# low loss with low accuracy in deep neural network

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, keras

I recently built a model for POS tagging. I tried an LSTM model and it works well, but I still want to add a CNN layer which rebuilds the original word's vector. The main problem is the flexible length of the sequence, which can be solved by a masking layer when in RNN, but that's not supported by the CNN. I still zero-pad the origin sequence to the MAXLEN and use it as the input of the CNN because the output of these extra words are still mostly zero, and can be solved by the masking layer.

But it seems very bad with low loss and low acc(0.342,0.298) compared with LSTM(0.478,0.871). What is the main reason for this? How can I solve the flexible length problem?'

```
input_seq = Input(shape=(None, input_dim), )
#conv，RELU
conv_out=Conv1D(
   filters=200,
   kernel_size=3,
   padding='same',
   activation='relu',
   use_bias=1,)(input_seq)
#zero pad 2 at head
pad_out=ZeroPadding1D(padding=(2,0))(conv_out)
#max_pool
pool_out=MaxPool1D(pool_size=3,strides=1,padding='valid')(pad_out)

# masking
mask_out = Masking(mask_value=0.0)(pool_out)
# LSTM
lstm_out = LSTM(units=hidden_unit, return_sequences=True)(mask_out)
# drop_out
drop_out = Dropout(drop_out_rate)(lstm_out)
# softmax
output_seq = TimeDistributed(Dense(output_dim, activation="softmax"))(drop_out)

# compile
model = Model(inputs=input_seq, outputs=output_seq)
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

the padding sequences' shape is x(Samples,MAXLEN,200),y(Samples,MAXLEN,42),i use zero-pad for each sequence of x and y.